# How can I animate a div on a click, and then reverse the animation on a second click?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I've spent quite a few hours trying anything i can but i can't find any answer so far.

I'm trying to create an animation where the visitor clicks on a square image, which will 'flip' to a trapeze shape much like the new Windows logo. from behind this element, at the same time, another div will slide out to the right with information regarding the image.

Creating this is fine, see a working example [on my site, here:](http://dxsxgn.com/dxsxgn)

( this currently only works in webkit browsers as i haven't got round to vendor prefixes and the div behind isn't sliding out correctly yet, but i'm sure you can understand what i'm trying to achieve here- something like the Windows 8 start screen tiles.)

The animation used is flipInY from animate.css with the middle keyframes removed. I was originally going to use Hover to run the animation however trying to implement this on a mobile site would be understandably difficult, so a jQuery 'onClick' event seemed like a better option.

I have managed to get the onClick switchClass JQuery function to work but only for the first animation, the second click just starts the animation again rather than truly reversing it. I'd include the code here but i removed it in search for a better solution which i haven't found.

[This question and answer goes a way to solving the problem, however it is for a different 'slideUp' animation and uses two different buttons, which i'd rather replace with one button that would toggle the effect.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915001/how-can-i-animate-my-div-to-slide-out-on-button-click)

I'd really appreciate any help, and if you think i'm attempting this in completely the wrong way please suggest something else!

Comment: Hey man, I love your design on your site!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not quite there yet but thanks for the appreciation!

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
animation-direction:alternate;
-webkit-animation-direction:alternate; /* Safari and Chrome */
```

very nice effects BTW :)

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't 'revert' the square to its original state, if you try the site again i've added this code but the animation only plays when i hover over the box, and it just snaps back to its original form when i move the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd use jQuery [`toggleClass();`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: I did try toggleClass, a combination of add/remove class and switchClass however it doesn't want to reverse the animation, or i'm doing it the wrong way. Simple transitions such as changing the background color works but what i'm trying to achieve might be too complicated, i can't see why though.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i not understand you but: [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oneng/H6wA3/1/)

html:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="over">yellow</div>
<div class="box">red</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('.over').click(function() {
$('.box').animate({marginLeft: '150',
                   width: '120',
                   height: '120',
                   marginTop: '-10'
                  }, 300);  


setTimeout( function(){
    $('.box').css('zIndex',80);
} , 400); 

$('.box').animate({marginLeft: '0'}, 300).animate({width: '100', height: '100', marginTop: '0'}, 300);
});

$('.box').click(function() {
$('.over').animate({
                    marginLeft: '150',
                    width: '120',
                    height: '120',
                    marginTop: '-10'
                    }, 300).css('zIndex',5); 

$('.box').css('zIndex',10);
setTimeout( function(){
    $('.over').css('zIndex',70);   
} , 400); 
$('.over').animate({
    marginLeft: '0'}, 300)
    .animate({width: '100',
          height: '100',
          marginTop: '0'}, 300);

});
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks very much! I've just had a quick go at adding some other animations in the Javascript such as changing the background color, is this possible?

Comment: 'm not sure that i understood you: background change with animation? like opacity with smoothly change in red color to yellow for example...

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

http://blog.guilhemmarty.com/flippy/jquery.flippy.min.js

```
$('#rectangle').click(function() {
  $(this).toggle(
      function(){
        $(this).flippy({
            color_target: "#aa0621",
            direction: "right",
            duration: "750"
         });
      },
      function(){
        $(this).flippy({
            color_target: "#aa0621",
            direction: "left",
            duration: "750"
         });
      }
  );
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/H6wA3/5/